# Clarification on the structure of my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

Some background info first. I require my app to show a feed of posts, implemented as cards. The data within the posts/cards is retrieved from my site's REST API. My app has 3 different tabs, each containing a different feed of posts/cards (but still the same layout).

Currently, I have an `activity_main` and the 3 fragments made for each tab (`fragment_1`, `fragment_2`, `fragment_3`). To my understanding, a `Fragment` is a layout that can be re-used on different `Activities`. Is this correct?

Additionally, where should I implement the layout/design for the cards? Should it be directly within the separate `Fragments` (even though the layout of the cards will be the same across all 3 tabs)?

After implementing the card layout, how would I populate the cards given the requested REST API json data? In other words, how would I loop through each result and insert the data into the card and display it on the screen?

Sorry for the noob questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently, I have an activity_main and the 3 fragments made for each
>   tab (fragment_1, fragment_2, fragment_3). To my understanding, a
>   Fragment is a layout that can be re-used on different Activities. Is
>   this correct?

Yes.

> Additionally, where should I implement the layout/design for the
>   cards? Should it be directly within the separate Fragments (even
>   though the layout of the cards will be the same across all 3 tabs)?

Have a single fragment. Create 3 instances of this fragment and inflate the same layout/design if the layout of the cards will be the same across all 3 tabs.

> After implementing the card layout, how would I populate the cards
>   given the requested REST API json data? In other words, how would I
>   loop through each result and insert the data into the card and display
>   it on the screen?

Pass a unique identifier that identifies the feeds (for this fragment) to the fragment as a bundle when you create a new instance and set them as the fragments argument. You can then retrieve this information to retrieve data relevant for this fragment.

To display the data, use a ListView/RecyclerView along with a suitable adapter to connect your data to your view.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Lets try this. Yes, you are right, Fragments are basically layouts that can be used in different Activities. As it says on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) site:

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities.

Having that said, since it is the same layout for all three tabs, you can use only one Fragment and populate it with different data. So if you want to change anything, you would do it only within that one fragment.

For the cards I am guessing that you will be using a custom ListView adapter. And that you should (must) implement outside the Fragments.

And regarding the last question, there are many libraries that make consuming ReST webservices much easier. For example [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).